# Why asp.net core 3.x use resource owner?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid

Some experts say that `resource owner` is a bad practice for authentication

[Scoot Brady - IdentityServer Team for example](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

Why Microsoft use the `resource owner` as the default flow in `asp.net core 3.0`?

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Is it safe to use `resource owner`?

When to use?

When not to use?

Comment: Does it? What makes you say it's the default?

Comment: @KirkLarkin i added link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO , the new Angular template(Individual authentication template ) **doesn't** use resource owner flow , in fact , it is using **Auth Code Flow + PKCE(PROOF Key for Code Exchange)** , which is already the official recommendation for native applications and SPAs . You can use Fiddler to trace the authentication requests :

Login request to authorize endpoint:

[image]

Checking the `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` , that is the code flow with PKCE . Also see the token request :

[image]

notice the `grant_type` .

[image]

In Code Flow+PKCE :

- In place of the `client_secret`(in normal code flow), the client app creates a random  value, `code_verifier`, which it hashes and encodes as a `code_challenge`.
- The Authorization Server stores the hashed value (the `Code Challenge`) for later verification and, after the user authenticates, redirects back to the app with an authorization code.
- The app makes the request to exchange the code for tokens, only it sends the Code Verifier instead of a fixed secret.

Comment: Thanks. Asp.net core spa use "Account" Area for view render